# Can "was to do" denote "the result of the past situation"?

Tags: infinitives

I've never come across "was to do" that is used to mean "the result of the past situation" as in

> 1. The football team was to win the trophy, defeating the opponent by
>      1-0 (meaning "the football team won the trophy, defeating the opponent by 1-0)
> 2. Issac Newton was to have lived his life in England in eighty years until he passed away.(meaning "Isaac Newton had lived his life in England in eighty years until he passed away.)

I think it's grammatically possible to use it like that if context is given enough to make the meaning definite.

Comment: These don't sound grammatical to me (a native speaker). From what context did you get the "was to do" construction?

Comment: The only examples of "was to do" I can think of are things like: "the purpose of the law *was to prevent* people from claiming bogus refunds from a company", "Sarah's intention *was to relocate* to France but then she met the partner of her dreams in her native Canada".

Comment: @seventyeightist, then, are there no sentences in which "was to do" can denote "the result of the past situation" ?

Comment: Do you just mean "the football team won the trophy" or is there some historical background like: they weren't expected to as they were a very inferior team, they lost people due to injuries (or whatever) but they *did* win despite all of that? Then you could say something like "The football team went on to win the trophy..." - which could also be used as a continuation like "they won the 1st round (?) and then went on to win the trophy".

"Went on"/"to go on" is a possible alternative if it's in the sense of contrary/continuation of something in the past which is relevant.

Comment: @seventyeightist I've just edited my question and written the intended meanings of both sentences.

Comment: ok, what do you mean by "if enough context is given to make the meaning definite"?

Comment: @seventyeightist That means if context is given enough, the meaning of "was to do" can denote definitely the result according to context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an odd form, not one I see often. I take it that this is used when the sapeaker is looking back into history, and then forward along a historical sequence. For example, the speaker looks at Newton's birth or early life, then uses this form to summarize the events of the rest of his life, or an aspect of them. Similarly for the team. I don't think this is wrong, but i do think it could and should be rewritten to improve the effect.

> Issac Newton was to have lived his life in England in eighty years until he passed away.

I would rewrite this as:

> Issac Newton would remain in England for all of the eighty years of his life.

or

> Issac Newton would live in England until he died eighty years later.

The other sentence

> The football team was to win the trophy, defeating the opponent by 1-0.

could be rewritten as:

> The football team would go on to win the trophy, defeating the opposing team 1-0.

or

> The football team went on to win the trophy, defeating the opposing team 1-0.

I mostly see  "was to do" forms in connection with plans that do not get carried out, such as:

> Jack was to have married Jill, but he died before the wedding date.
>
> George was to be promoted to manager, but he moved and Jane took the position.

Comment: If we wrote like this "The worst thing I did ever was to marry my ex-wife", could "to marey" make this sentence mean "The worst thing I did ever was that I married my ex-wife" ?

Comment: @Floret, yes that is what your sentence means, but in it "to marry" is the infinitive form of the verb, not part of a "was to" form. This sentence is "The worst thing I ever did was X" where X="marry my ex-wife". In fact if the "to" is left out, it is still an infinitive and the meaning is unchanged. By the way, this is technically ambiguous. "Marry my ex-wife" should mean "marry Jane, now my ex-wife" but it could  mean "RE-marry Jane, then my ex-wife."

Comment: You can use 'was to' about events in the past, but which were in the future at some earlier time; in 1733 George Washington was a fat baby who was to become President of the United States.

Comment: @Michael Harvey yes indeed, but I don't see "was to **have**"  used in that context.

Comment: @Michael Harvey, but those who don't know about George Washington even at all can't be sure, only with the sentence, whether that fat baby really became President of the US or not?

Comment: The writer knows, and he or she is telling the reader.

Comment: In December 1799, Washington was to have become 67 years old, but he died on the 14th.